# Dealing with time objects in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I  am working with a Pandas Series that contains (Date/Time) Strings of the form: 
"2020-04-01 09:29:21"-"2020-04-01 09:53:17"-"2020-04-13 09:55:55"-.....).

The format is : "yyyy-mm-dd H:M:s".

I am only interested in the hour and minute components and I am looking for a way to divide the data into 30 minute buckets and count the values in each bucket.

An example of my end  result:

```
   Range         count       
  9:00-9:30        7
  9:30-10:00       25
 10:00-10:30       35.......
```

Comment: Take a look at ```resample```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resample first and then do a groupby the time. Lets us create a serie and set the index to DateTimeIndex otherwise resample won't work:

```
# random data
np.random.seed(0)
serie = pd.Series(
    np.random.choice(pd.date_range(
        '2020-01-01', freq='7T22S', periods=10000), 1000)
)
serie.index = serie
```

Do a resample and then do a groupby:

```
res = serie.resample('30T').count()
results = res.groupby(res.index.time).sum()

#Change the index to match the format
results.index = results.index.astype(str) + ' - ' +\
            np.roll(results.index.astype(str), -1)

results.head()

# 00:00:00 - 00:30:00    19
# 00:30:00 - 01:00:00    25
# 01:00:00 - 01:30:00    19
# 01:30:00 - 02:00:00    28
# 02:00:00 - 02:30:00    22
```